# What happens if import statements can not be resolved?

Tags: java, class, jvm, classloader

I am not clear on the following:
A class is loaded by JVM when needed, like lazy initialization, right?
Now if class `A` does an `import` of class `B` which class `B` actually is not in the file system (e.g. `B.class` was deleted or not delivered or any reason)
then does class `A` get loaded and runs **if** no method of class `B` is called?
*Or* class `A` is not able to run at all since the imports can not be resolved?
*Or* class `A` is loaded and run up to a certain point?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`import` statement is only important for the compiler. In bytecode all references to other classes are fully qualified. That's why superflous imports don't matter at runtime.

In your case JVM will try to load all classes that are required to load and verify `A`<del>, so it will try to load `B` immediately</del>, but dependant classes are loaded lazily only when they are needed. Check out the following example:

```
public class A {

    public static void bar() {
        new B().foo();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //bar();
    }

}
```

Compile `A.java` and delete `B.class`. Without calling `bar()` method your program will run just fine. But once you uncomment piece of code actually using `B` class you'll get nasty:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: B
    at A.bar(A.java:4)
    at A.main(A.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: B
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 2 more
```

If `B` is not available, you'll get `NoClassDefFound` or similar.

Comment: So this will happen trying to resolve the `imports`?Right. Right on constructing class `A`?

Comment: @Jim: No, JVM is **not** resolving any imports, imports are read and discarded during compilation. They don't exist in bytecode. In `.class` file all classes are fully qualified.

Comment: +1 I love it when to go to great length and in detail to explain exactly why "issue X" could not ever be a problem and they come back with; so its a real problem then. LOL.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz:In your code I assume that you forgot the `import` for class `B`?

Comment: @Jim: I was testing this in the same package, so no import was necessary. Feel free to use the same test code, but in different packages. But I guarantee that the results will be the same.

Comment: So my understanding is correct.As long as a method/class is not directly used, no runtime issue occurs.Right?

Comment: @Jim: initially I thought that classes are loaded eagerly, but my test above proves you are right.

Answer (score 0):

If A.class require B.class which is missing. A.class can not be loaded.

Loading class is a `recursion operation`.

When A.class require B.class, the JVM search B.class in `PermGen`. If B.class is loaded and store in `PermGen`, JVM will `not reload` the B.class but get it  from `PermGen` directly, otherwrise the JVM will load B.class recursively.

When JVM can not find B.class, it throw `NoClassDefFoundError`.

[See more about NoClassDefFoundError in [Java Specification] :page 319](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf).

Comment: Yes ok.But the question is *when exactly* is this exception thrown

Answer (score 0):

You will get NoClassDefFoundError when you call the method that uses the definition of B.class. This will cause the class loader to search for B.class and load it in memory.

AFAIK there is one exception to this rule, Annotations. When you have an annotation that cannot be found at run time it will be ignored in some cases, see: [Why doesn't a missing annotation cause a ClassNotFoundException at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567413/why-doesnt-a-missing-annotation-cause-a-classnotfoundexception-at-runtime)